# Buying IPhone in another person name without contract (withoutcontract)

Tags: iphone, warranty

Can I buy an iPhone in another person's name because I will be gifting it to him so that he can claim under they warranty if anything comes up in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The warranty is tight to the device via serial number, not the purchaser name.